# "Rename from commit-graph.lock to commit-graph failed " when running git commands from a batch file

Tags: git, batch-file, github

I have written a batch file to automate a series of `git add/commit/push` actions but I am getting hit with a `Rename from  commit-graph.lock to commit-graph failed` messages, see attached pic. My batch file  has several of this 3-line snippet copied one below another as follows

```
git add 10\14*\*.csv 
git commit -m "updating files" 
git push origin master 

git add 10\15*\*.csv 
git commit -m "updating files"  
git push origin master
```

I think the `y/n` messages is dropped with the `git commit` is called (but I am not sure). Answering 'y' gives me back the same message while answering 'n' looks to work ok, commit is executed, files pushed upstream and it moves to the next set of commands until the lock is raised again..

I have rebooted the pc, and ran the batch file without any other programs open (at least manually) but to no avail. Also I dont think there is another process that locks the file.

Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: Is `D:` a shared drive of some sort? This could be a WIndows-specific issue that only happens on such drives. Your precise Git version may be of interest as well since the new commit-graph code has only been around for a bit over a year at this point.

Comment: My `D` drive is my second local SSD drive sitting on my motherboad. However the folder syncs with `Micosoft's OneDrive`, hence the path to my repo looks like `D:\Home\OneDrive\xxx\xxx`. My git version is: `git version 2.26.0.windows.1`

Comment: Oh. Never point Git at a folder it cannot control 100%.

Comment: I am moving it now outside the OneDrive folder, I let you know how it goes but i will take a while., Thanks

Comment: Hm, signed out from `OneDrive`, moved my repo outside `OneDrive's` sync folder, rebooted pc,(OneDrive still not signed in, but it shouldnt matter now) but I still get the same message. Also to add, I am always launching the windows `command prompt` as an admin. Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK, it's probably a bug in Git 2.26.0-for-Windows, at this point. If you have a way to reproduce it, you can file a bug report with the Git folks.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your replies in any case!. If I can reproduce it I will report a bug. I did something similar, (different repo, different files, but same logic: git commits via a batch file) about a year ago without any problems at all. From your comments however I understand that the commit-graph code may to even existed at the time..

Comment: Had the same problem remaining after restart. However, after `git prune` the message disappeared.

Comment: @VasilenDonchev Ah ok, good to know, I will try it next time the same thing happens. I didnt find a solution, I tried `git gc --force` but didnt make a difference

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will be useful for someone later: for me the issue was the other app (VS Code) was using this file. As soon as I closed it, the problem disappeared. Maybe that one can also help you.

Comment: If you have installed some extensions in VSCode, like GitLens, It will cause this problem.